# Nullable типы и универсальная проверка на Null

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, я хочу сделать универсальный метод IsNullOrEmpty, который на вход может принять тип T.

Возникла проблема с проверкой Nullable типа на то имеет ли он значение или нет.

Т.е вот я узнал, что передомною Nullable, но

```
if (T is Nullable<T> nullable)
```

не работает и ругается, что так делать нельзя...

Как я могу сделать задуманное и удостовериться, что HasValue возвращает true или false?

Comment: Сюда заглядывали? https://stackoverflow.com/a/374663/8324991

Comment: @CrazyElf да, но тут проверка на Nullable тип только, а мне нужно зная, что тип Nullable понять, есть ли у него значение отличное от null или нет, а это по идее можно понять через HasValue

Comment: Что-то я не понял. Если как там по ссылке принять на вход метода именно `Nullable<T>` то дальше всё что угодно легко проверить. Вот наоборот `T` попытаться скастовать в `Nullable<T>`, как это пытаетесь сделать вы, видимо, нельзя. Ну, если я хоть что-то понял.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый простой рабочий вариант - обычная проверка на null:

```
static bool IsNull<T>(T val)
{
    return val == null;
}

Console.WriteLine(IsNull((int?)null)); // True
Console.WriteLine(IsNull(5));          // False
```

Comment: Хм... Мне казалось, что обычной проверки на null недостаточно, так Nullable-это вроде как структура, а оно вот как просто оказалось.